# One line query for has and belongs to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using many to many relationship in my model class, and I am trying to write one line query to fetch all articles and tags associated with 
that in a Array form. Can somebody help me with the code?

For example I need sample below mentioned output.

```
['Article_id', 'Article_name', 'Tag_id', 'Tag_name']

['1', 'Sample', '2', 'sample']
['1', 'Sample', '3', 'sample']
```

Model Class:-

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by joining both tables and using pluck to return only a specific list of attributes in a nested array:

```
Article.joins(:tags).pluck('articles.id, articles.name, tags.id, tags.name')
```

Comment: hey thanks! for your reply, but I am getting result like, [[2, "Elizabeth", 2, "Chance"], [3, "Julio", 3, "Shawanna"]], how to remove outer array from this?

Comment: The outer array is the container (or list) for the nested arrays (the elements of the list). You cannot "remove" the outer array, you need something to organizes the elements. But I think that is not really your question. And your question is not clear about what you want to do with that list (Show it on a page, write it to a file, print it in the console)? Perhaps your question is: How to print such a list in the console, then just iterated through that list and call `puts` in every single item: `.each { |element| puts(element) }`